# How to submit an array of values in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form which has input type checkbox.These checkboxes are being displayed dynamically by fetching data from the database. And i have given each input checkbox its own id as a html attribute. The user can tick or check more than one option, in php i can put something like values[] and then submit, loop and get my values.

My question is that, how can i submit the checked options as an array using javascript or jquery to a php function and then loop to get each individual value?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: First, for each of checkbox i have added a *class='steps[]'* and to my jquery i used *let supplement_options = $('.steps[]').val();* but seems not to work the form fails to submit and the submit is being disabled

Comment: As per the jQuery docs, .val() only returns the value of the first element in the set of matched elements. You'd need to loop them and get each value individually. Or you might be better just to use jQuery's serialize function. It's hard to know for sure without seeing any existing code in context

Answer (score 0):

html and js code

```
<form>
    <label for="red">红色</label>
    <input name="checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox">

    <label for="yellow">黄色</label>
    <input name="checkbox" value="2" type="checkbox">

    <label for="blue">蓝色</label>
    <input name="checkbox" value="3" type="checkbox">

    <input value="全选" onclick="allPick()" type="button">

    <!-- Store the acquired value -->
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="value" id="value">
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="confirm" value="confirm">
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function allPick() {
        $("[type=checkbox]:checkbox").each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
        })
    }

    console.log(text);
    //output: 1,2,3
     
    $("input[name='confirm']").click(function (e) {
        text = $("input:checkbox[name='checkbox']:checked").map(function(index,elem) {
            return $(elem).val();
        }).get().join(',');

        // The first form submission method
        $("input[name='value']").val(text);

        //The second Ajax submission method
        $.post(url,{value:text},function(result){
            console.log(result);
        });
    })
</script>
```

php code

[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode)

```
$value = $_POST['value'];
$pieces = explode(",", $value);
print_r($pieces);
//output:
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)


*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute selector like

```
$('input[name="checkbox"]:checked');
```

to select all checked inputs with name "checkbox"

```
console.log($('input[name="checkbox"]:checked').serialize());

//or

$('input[name="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
   console.log(this.value);
});
```